# No more data to read from socket after execute this sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Why when I execute this SQL using SQL Developer it said

> ```
> No more data to read from socket
> ```

but when I reconnect the connection then remove `fetch next 5 rows only` it executes perfectly?

It also happens when I execute this query on web application, it gives this error:

> ```
> oci_execute(): ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
> Process ID: 4136
> Session ID: 18
> Serial number: 36957
> ```

```
SELECT PO_ID,
       ENQ_ID,
       TITLE,
       SYS_BRKDWN_ID,
       TECH_HAND_USR_ID,
       PROJ_NO,
       SUPPL_NO,
       approver_usr_id,
       VER
FROM   S181 
WHERE  approver_usr_id ='EETEC'
and    reject_date is null
AND    po_hdr_biz.can_approve(po_id, enq_id, ver,'EETEC') = 1
AND    EXISTS (
  SELECT NULL
  FROM   po_approvals
  WHERE  po_approvals.po_id = s181.po_id
  AND    po_approvals.ver = s181.ver
  AND    po_approvals.init = 'EETEC'
  AND    po_approvals.init = s181.approver_usr_id
  AND    po_approvals.po_id IS NOT NULL
  AND    po_approvals.approve_date IS NULL
UNION
  SELECT NULL
  FROM   po_approvals
  WHERE  po_approvals.enq_id = s181.enq_id 
  AND    po_approvals.ver = s181.ver 
  AND    po_approvals.init = 'EETEC'
  AND    po_approvals.init = s181.approver_usr_id 
  AND    po_approvals.enq_id IS NOT NULL
  FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
);
```

Comment: Seems odd to have a row-limiting clause inside an `exists` subquery. Is it really needed?

Comment: tq i have found the solution i have to put braket before **)fetch next 5 row only;** but i dont understand why oracle show error **no more data socket**

Comment: It's a generic error stack produced when the server process crashes. Your client process is fetching data when suddenly the server process it's talking to drops off, hence *No more data to read from socket* and  *end-of-file on communication channel*. (It should really give a more detailed error instead of crashing, so I guess there you have hit an Oracle bug whereby it accepts syntax it can't actually handle.)